# Win7Pro: Capturing a photo and recording voice when someone failed to login

Tags: windows-7, security

I'm looking for a solution to capture a photo by internal camera and recording voice by mic of laptop when someone failed to login my Laptop of companies.

Because, Somebody did removed my password of Outlook last time. So, I set new complicated password on Windows 7 Pro. But, Somebody have been trying to login in my laptop physically during my absence and also the inside of my baggage is moved sometimes. I can easily detect it.  Because, I have specific custom to keep them such enabling group policy, remembering the position of inside of baggage and so on.

If you could provide me a solution that would be appreciated.

Sincerely,

Comment: You will have to locate a solution yourself. What you describe would require third-party software.  There isn't a native solution built into Windows 7, nor any version of Windows 7, but definitely not Windows 7.  *This sounds like a human behaviour problem.*  If people at work are attempting to use your computer, first off they might have a legitimate reason to access your company computer, but I doubt they need your account password to do that.  Additionally, if they are going through your stuff, take steps to prevent that.  This isn't a issue we can help with.

Comment: @Ramhoud, Thank you for your response. I see. I will feedback to Microsoft to implement the solution in new Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [CommandCam](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/commandcam/) can help you I don't think he can rec voice, unfortunately.

[Here's](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/snap-picture-log-in-save-to-dropbox/) a tutorial about it.

---

Actually, these kinds of things should be solved by human talking.
You can discuss with the [interpersonal community](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) they will be more able to answer questions about problems of human to human.

Comment: Please if you downvote give a reason.

Comment: You linked to a tutorial but you didn't include the tutorial in your answer.

Comment: @DIDIx13, Thank you for the information. I will check and try it.